# ListView footer width

Tags: android, listview, layout, footer

I have a problem with an footer for the listview(I can't center the footer).

I'm using a footer for an endless list.

The problem I'm having is that the footer is not stretched to match the list width(instead is somehow using wrap_content).

This is the footer layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Loading more..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I add the footer to the listview:

```
View footerView;

...     

// Get the custom layout for footer
        footerView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().
                inflate(R.layout.list_footer_load_more, getListView(), false);
        LinearLayout footerViewLayout = (LinearLayout) footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
        // Adding custom view to ListView at footer
        getListView().addFooterView(footerViewLayout, null, false);
```

And this is how the final result looks like:
(I can't post images on stackoverflow, but here is an outside link to the image)
http://s21.postimg.org/3zkd7pic7/listview_footer_problem.png

I tried everything to center the footer but nothing worked. I'm hoping someone can help me, because this is stressing me out for some time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your footer layout(R.layout.list_footer_load_more) to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Loading more..." />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Change your code to:

```
View footerView;

...     

// Get the custom layout for footer
footerView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().
            inflate(R.layout.list_footer_load_more, null);
RelativeLayout footerViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
    // Adding custom view to ListView at footer
    getListView().addFooterView(footerViewLayout, null, false);
```

Comment: Sadly it is still the same

Comment: @IonutNegru And, when inflating `R.id.footer_layout`, use `inflate(R.layout.list_footer_load_more, null);`

Comment: It is still aligned wrong ... and it got a little buggy(it moves a little :) - don't know why)

Comment: @IonutNegru not sure what's wrong then. May be someone else here can help you out.

Comment: OMG, I found the problem ... 

The list was loaded through an fragment 
` <fragment
     android:id="@+id/my_list"
     android:name="com.example.ListFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     tools:context="com.example.ListActivity"
     tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />` 
and I forgot to set the width to match_parent in here ...
now it's working like I want it :) ... 
anyway thanks for all the help ... I will mark your answer as correct because this is still a method to load the footer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't mark your answer, I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @IonutNegru Hey, nice catch! And it's fine. You can mark it when you have enough rep. Good luck.